# Docker build in Azure devops failing with message Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis,

Tags: azure, docker, .net-core, azure-devops, entity-framework-core

I have a Docker build running as a task in an Azure devops build pipeline. Recently I had to add a git submodule to the project which contains a .Net Standard 2.0 library which references Entity Framework Core. Now when I run the build I get the following error message:

> CSC : error CS8032: An instance of analyzer
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RawSqlStringInjectionDiagnosticAnalyzer
>   cannot be created from
>   /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.analyzers/2.2.1/analyzers/dotnet/cs/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers.dll
>   : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis,
>   Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.. [/.../MyProject.csproj]

I have tried adding the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis nuget package to the project but that just causes more error messages. I have also tried adding Microsoft.Net.Compilers but that can only build under the full .Net framework so doesn't work for other areas of our pipeline.

The build agent being used is Hosted Ubuntu 1604 which should have the most up to date .NEt core SDK. Everything compiles locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I was targeting an old .Net version in the dockerfile.

Old command:

`FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0.0 as build`

New command:

`FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build as build`